# Error running small keras model on shared hosting

Tags: tensorflow

I am using Google's Teachable Machine to export a very small keras_model.h5 file. It runs fine on my localhost, but when I upload it to a shared hosting cpanel and try to run it in the terminal with the following configuration:
CPU 1 Core
Physical Memory 1 GB
IO 5 MB
Entry Processes 50
I get an error as shown below.

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Feb 21 2023, 16:34:36)
[GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-16)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from keras.models import load_model
>>> from PIL import Image,ImageOps
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import sys
>>> np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
>>> model = load_model("keras_model.h5", compile=False)
2023-04-11 09:06:55.330819: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-04-11 09:06:55.338629: F tensorflow/core/platform/default/env.cc:73] Check failed: ret == 0 (11 vs. 0)Thread tf_Compute creation via pthread_create() failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If this is a fixable error, I would appreciate your help in fixing it.
If it's due to insufficient configuration, I would appreciate your suggestions for a better hosting configuration or a suitable VPS. What hosting configuration or VPS do you use?